# Editing Bluebox chapterstyle

Tags: memoir, chapters

[image: Current layout]

I have this edited version of `BlueBox`, but I would like the number in the box to be centred and on line with the chapter name. Also I would like the text on top of the box (chapter in Danish) to disappear.

```
\usepackage{fourier} % or what ever
\usepackage[scaled=1]{helvet}%. Sans serif - Helvetica
\usepackage{color,calc}
\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
\definecolor{Skyblaa}{RGB}{0,153,255}
\makeatletter
\newcommand
*
{\thickhrulefill}{%
\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand
*
\BuildChpNum[2]{%
  \llap{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut} \\[0.5ex]
  \colorbox{Skyblaa}{%
\rule[-4em]{0pt}{0pt}%
\rule{1.5ex}{0pt}\color{black}#2\strut
\rule{1.5ex}{0pt}}%
  \end{tabular}\hspace{0cm}%
}}



\makechapterstyle{BlueBox}{%
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\Huge\bfseries}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{15pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
\sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
\BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}
\renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
\sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
\BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
{\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}}}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
\vspace{\midchapskip}%
\thickhrulefill\par
\chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%
}
\chapterstyle{BlueBox}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the full code, not only fragments

Comment: The code is 250 lines, and i aren't allowed to make at viewable like, the styling is

Comment: It's incomplete still. It's not compilable